# Adding Multi-channel guests to channel with Slack Api

Tags: python, slack-api

My org has Slack's Pro plan. I'm trying to add users to a channel the api [conversation.invite](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.invite) method in Python. I'm able to add regular members, but the api is returning an error when I try to add "Multi-Channel Guests":

```
'error': 'user_is_restricted'
```

I'm able to manually add those guests to the channel, so not sure where the problem is.

These are the details of the channel:

```
{'ok': True, 'channel': {'id': 'xxxxx', 'name': 'xxxx', 'is_channel': True, 'is_group': False, 'is_im': False, 'is_mpim': False, 'is_private': False, 'created': 1679535429, 'is_archived': False, 'is_general': False, 'unlinked': 0, 'name_normalized': 'ar001_dely', 'is_shared': False, 'is_org_shared': False, 'is_pending_ext_shared': False, 'pending_shared': [], 'context_team_id': 'T0XRJN529', 'updated': 1679535429777, 'parent_conversation': None, 'creator': 'xxxxx', 'is_ext_shared': False, 'shared_team_ids': ['xxxx'], 'pending_connected_team_ids': [], 'is_member': True, 'last_read': '0000000000.000000', 'topic': {'value': 'xx', 'creator': 'xxxx', 'last_set': 1679535429}, 'purpose': {'value': 'xxx', 'creator': 'xxxx', 'last_set': 1679535429}, 'previous_names': []}}
```

Comment: Slack's info for that error is "An invited user is a guest user that is restricted from accessing this conversation." But then why can I manually add the guest user to the channel?

Comment: Are you using a User Token to execute the conversations.invite request? Does the token is from an admin?

Comment: I'm using a bot with all the required auths. The problem seems that you can't automatically add guest (even multi-channel guests), only users.

Comment: Try executing the method with a User token from an admin instead of a bot token. The documentation suggests that only an admin can invite a guest to a public channel: https://slack.com/help/articles/202518103-Understand-guest-roles-in-Slack (fourth item on the table)